# Finding "id" row in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a part of my login script that should find the "id" of the user attempting to login ("id" being a column in the MySQL table). Instead it gives this output:

```
Array ( [id] => id ) 1
```

I used print_r(); to find this output, but I do not plan on using it for the rest of the development period.

I want to use the "id" of a user to find the rest of their database content echo it if necessary.

```
//get id of user  logging in

$get_id = mysql_query("SELECT 'id' from users WHERE username = '{$username_login}'") or die(mysql_error());

$id = print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($get_id));

// test echo for id

echo $id;
```

In this script, $username_login is defined earlier in the script, and is not shown here.

The "id" of the testing user that I have is 1, as is shown is phpMyAdmin.

By the way, when I tested without print_r, it echoed "Array" (without quotes, obviously).

Appreciate the help.

-ethan17458

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$get_id = mysql_query("SELECT `id` from users WHERE username = '{$username_login}'") or die(mysql_error());

$id = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_id);

echo $id['id'];
```

Comment: Thanks so much. StackOverflow is definitely one of the best communities on the internet. Thanks for the help, and I will continue growing my knowledge of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

never use quotes (`'` or `"`) in database column name or table name. you can use backticks( `)

change this line :

```
mysql_query("SELECT 'id' from users WHERE username = '{$username_login}'") or die(mysql_error());
```

to:

```
mysql_query("SELECT `id` from users WHERE username = '{$username_login}'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

- When you list **columns** in a mysql query, you should put them in ``` `` ```, not in `''` or `""`.
- When you list **values** in a mysql query, you should put them in `''` or
  `""`, not in ``` `` ```.
  If the values are **numbers** you don't have to put them in quotes.